# Deep linking is not working in SwiftUI iOS (open url appdelegate method is not triggerd)?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, deep-linking, sfsafariviewcontroller

I am working on SwiftUI app in which trying to perform deep linking.
when I manually open the browser and put "myapp://" its navigating to app correctly.
But in actual I am opening safari within app and after deep link success I want to call below appdelegate method

I am using sfsafariviewcontroller

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
            print("myapp")
        return true
    }
```

below is my work

[image]

Thank You for help

Comment: any soultion you got for this? i also need same help

Comment: also set URL identifier to "myapp"

Answer (score 0):

```
@main
struct SomeApp: App {
    var body: some Scene{
        WindowGroup{
            Content()
                .onOpenURL{url in
                    //handle any action from deep link
                }
        }
    }
}

struct Content: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}
```

After set deeplink in info.plist you can handle deeplink via method onOpenURL

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation this method seems to be the one you can directly use with SFSafariViewController

```swift
func safariViewController(_ controller: SFSafariViewController, 
            didCompleteInitialLoad didLoadSuccessfully: Bool)
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontrollerdelegate/1621215-safariviewcontroller)